# Custom scrollbar

Tags: javascript, css, scrollbar, jscrollpane

I am hoping to incorporate custom scrollbars in my site as there are divs with set heights that will overflow. I have managed to get exactly what I want using webkit styling in css however I am aware that there will be issues when looking at the site in Firefox or IE.

As a result, I tried to incorporate the jScrollPane library into my site but its causing all sorts of js "clashes" which is throwing the whole site into a mess!

Are there any simpler methods to customise my scroll bar so that I have cross browser compatibility without adding a new js page to the site?

Alternatively - is there a way I can attach something to the css for when the browser is firefox!?

Thanks
JD

Comment: The [`-moz` specific CSS extensions are listed on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS_Reference/Mozilla_Extensions).

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357203/custom-scrollbars/32424642#32424642

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little confused with what exactly you're asking for, but if you're looking for a scroll bar of some sort that can be customized with CSS, look no further than [jQuery UI's Slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/).

You'll have to add some event handlers to do the scrolling, but it shouldn't be too difficult over-all.

Answer (score 1):

Fast forward to 2017, and there are a lot of good custom scrollbar scripts these days. By good I mean ones that rely on native scrolling mechanics and works on mobile devices too. The one I use is [Perfect Scrollbar](https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar). Some other good ones can be [found here](http://blog.dynamicdrive.com/top-7-custom-scrollbar-javascript-and-jquery-plugins/) in this blog post.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some custom scrollbars you can use:
http://www.net-kit.com/jquery-custom-scrollbar-plugins/

One off these solutions should work. BTW i use JScrollpane and it works like a charm for me

Comment: Hi Luuk - thanks for the response - have run through these examples and tried them out but cannot seem to get them working without interfering with my current javascript! very frustrating.....

Answer (score 0):

I went through all of the suggestions above and was disappointed by either of the following issues:

1. poor cross-browser compatibility
2. lag
3. a lot of redundant code/ dependencies (jQuery UI)

Therefore, I've used some CSS trickery and JavaScript (depends on jQuery selectors) to build my own custom scrollbar implementation. The demo is available at https://dev.anuary.com/680a3c94-9651-550f-abca-e853613eb9ce/. The source code is hosted at https://github.com/anuary/jquery-custom-scrollbar.

My approach relies on the native browser scrollbar. However, this implementation does not support horizontal scrollbars.

Comment: Both of the links are dead now. Consider updating your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just found this, without jQuery, if anyone is interested:

http://www.script-tutorials.com/custom-scrollbars-cross-browser-solution/