# custom scrollbar without jquery

Tags: javascript, scrollbar

I'm looking for a custom scrollbar that works without jquery. I can't use jquery because the other stuff is also jqueryless and it's optimized for fast loading.

Would be grateful for any ideas shared with me.

NONNNNN

Comment: Specify what about the scrollbar you want to customize. You can do some things with just CSS.

Comment: yeah i know that i can style the webkit scrollbars just with css. but i need a bit more than just the style. the scrollbar has to be over the content like on android or ios.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27322881/how-can-i-create-a-simple-page-vertical-scroll-bar-without-using-jquery/28666991#28666991

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357203/custom-scrollbars/32424642#32424642

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to use jQuery you could always attempt CSS (only works in WebKit).

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/EKdDa/1/)

Example CSS:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 15px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
   background-color: #000000;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
   border-radius: 10px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
   background-color: #555555;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
   background-color: #000000;
   background-image: url(dark/light-blue/images/ui-icons_0990fb_256x240.png);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment {
   background-position: -64px -16px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement {
   background-position: 0 -16px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:increment {
   background-position: -32px -16px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:decrement {
   background-position: -96px -16px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
   background-color: #000000;
}
```

[More on WebKit Custom Scrollbars](http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/)

If you want multiple browser support you'll want to use jQuery or write your own custom javascript code with appending a div for the scrollbar and adding Event Handlers to know when you scroll.

[Example of Custom Scrollbar Code](http://jsfiddle.net/dVsVq/21/)

Comment: yeah i know that i can style the webkit scrollbars just with css. but i need a bit more than just the style. the scrollbar has to be over the content like on android or ios devices.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for peoples who are looking also for a nice scrollbar without dependencies:

You can use [IScroll](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/) if you need a bit more than just a scrollbar or the [Gemini Scrollbar](https://github.com/noeldelgado/gemini-scrollbar), which is absolutely amazing and uses native scrolling behaviour.