# make only vertical scrolling invisible

Tags: css, scrollbar

Hi I want to make vertical scrolling invisible, but i want to left the horizontal scrollbar visible. 
Also I want my page be scrollable both vertically and horizontally.

I used:

```
.my_class::-webkit-scrollbar{
    display: none;
    }
```

but it make both scrollbar invisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to say that using simple css trick, you wont be able to achieve this.

I suggest you d use custom scrollbar plugins, by which you can simply apply css trick for each scrollbar type, like following:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".container").customScrollbar();
});
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 100px;
}

.container .overview {
  width: 800px;
}

.scrollable .scroll-bar.horizontal {
  background: #eee; height: 5px; border-radius: 20px;
}
.scrollable .scroll-bar.horizontal .thumb {
  background: #999; 
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/mzubala/jquery-custom-scrollbar/master/jquery.custom-scrollbar.css" />
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mzubala/jquery-custom-scrollbar/master/jquery.custom-scrollbar.js"></script>

<div class="container">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Proin nibh augue, suscipit a, scelerisque sed, lacinia in, mi. Cras vel lorem. Etiam pellentesque aliquet tellus. Phasellus pharetra nulla ac diam. Quisque semper justo at risus. Donec venenatis, turpis vel hendrerit interdum, dui ligula ultricies purus, sed posuere libero dui id orci. Nam congue, pede vitae dapibus aliquet, elit magna vulputate arcu, vel tempus metus leo non est. Etiam sit amet lectus quis est congue mollis. Phasellus congue lacus eget neque. Phasellus ornare, ante vitae consectetuer consequat, purus sapien ultricies dolor, et mollis pede metus eget nisi. Praesent sodales velit quis augue. Cras suscipit, urna at aliquam rhoncus, urna quam viverra nisi, in interdum massa nibh nec erat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Proin nibh augue, suscipit a, scelerisque sed, lacinia in, mi. Cras vel lorem. Etiam pellentesque aliquet tellus. Phasellus pharetra nulla ac diam. Quisque semper justo at risus. Donec venenatis, turpis vel hendrerit interdum, dui ligula ultricies purus, sed posuere libero dui id orci. Nam congue, pede vitae dapibus aliquet, elit magna vulputate arcu, vel tempus metus leo non est. Etiam sit amet lectus quis est congue mollis. Phasellus congue lacus eget neque. Phasellus ornare, ante vitae consectetuer consequat, purus sapien ultricies dolor, et mollis pede metus eget nisi. Praesent sodales velit quis augue. Cras suscipit, urna at aliquam rhoncus, urna quam viverra nisi, in interdum massa nibh nec erat.
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you.
Although it worked fine for me, but this method required to add jquery library, I wonder if is there any way with out using jquery.

Comment: @ArashRabiee Well, you can use pure javascript plugin then instead, afraid I never tried such a plugin before though. Please try to search on Google, or check this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684304/custom-scrollbar-without-jquery

Answer (score 2):

```
overflow-y: hidden; // hide vertical
overflow-x: hidden; // hide horizontal
```

These two CSS properties can be used to hide the scrollbars.

Comment: Hi, as I mentioned in @Amal, I want to make vertical scrollbar hidden, and my content stay scrollable.

Comment: A similar query is answered here [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll) Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Use over flow  property :
`overflow-y: hidden`

Comment: Hi, property overflow-y: hidden, make that part of content which is overflowed hidden, and not scrollable,
I want my vertical scrollbar be hidden, not content.
my content still be scrollable,